# GPS Navigation Service for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, navigationservice

I am writing application in WP7 for traveling. Is it possible to navigate to GPS coordinate with Bing Maps on WP7.

I mean I have GPS coordinate, button "travel to" and after clicking it I'll have route to that point (by Bing Service)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this on Windows Phone 7, but judging by [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394024%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) it also applies to WP 7.1.

Here's the sample:

```
BingMapsDirectionsTask bingMapsDirectionsTask = new BingMapsDirectionsTask();

// You can specify a label and a geocoordinate for the end point.
// GeoCoordinate spaceNeedleLocation = new GeoCoordinate(47.6204,-122.3493);
// LabeledMapLocation spaceNeedleLML = new LabeledMapLocation("Space Needle",     spaceNeedleLocation);

// If you set the geocoordinate parameter to null, the label parameter is used as a   search term.
LabeledMapLocation spaceNeedleLML = new LabeledMapLocation("Space Needle", null);

bingMapsDirectionsTask.End = spaceNeedleLML;

// If bingMapsDirectionsTask.Start is not set, the user's current location is used as the start point.

 bingMapsDirectionsTask.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open Here Drive (by Nokia) with the following URI scheme:

```
guidance-drive://v2.0/navigate/destination/?latlon=52.53,13.41&title=Museum
```

This will switch app, then start navigating to `52.52/13.41`. The title is optional.

Source: http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/maps-and-navigation/here-launchers/wp-uri-schemes-for-location-applications/drive-guidance.html